# Table showing detail view and return to the same place in tableview

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter, tableview

I'm doing a simple twitter client. (`TableView` that talk is the TimeLine).

The User selects a `Tweet` from `Tableview` and thus through a `Segue`, appears a view with all the details of the `Tweet`, but when the User returns to the `TableView` `ViewDidLoad` method is executed, and that the method to get data from `TimeLine` is activated, and by consequence the tableview back to the top (which is very boring).
I wanted to see the User details Tweet and when they returned to the `TableView tweet` it was in the same position on the left User.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView have a convinient method to do that
`- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated`

[Reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @LcstestTest you need to cache it when you get your `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath` call delegate call back when the cell got selected